# Connection string for MySQL database on webserver having shared IP address - C#

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I am new to MySQL database, I want to Get or Set data into my database by using my C# winform application, therefore I need to know the required connection string for my database present on a webserver having shared IP address. The name of my database is `shop_ListDatabase`, The shared IP address of my website is `91.215.159.xxx`, consider user name and password is (UserName, Password), website is example.com.

I have searched many hours on the internet but did not find suitable answer. The search results are all about Database on a local machine, but my database in on my website.

Comment: Even if you send a request from the same server, just setting your connection to "localhost" may prevent you from connecting with an ip address. You can try setting it to connect from any computer ( % ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the port. Default port is: 3306, in that case your connection string should be something like :

```
Server=91.215.159.xxx;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: Following error occures: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. My port is 2082

Comment: Are you just having trouble connecting through PHP or can you not establish a connection to MySQL from the command line as well? If you cannot connect at all, verify the service is running and listening on port 2082 .

Comment: @Farid-ur-Rahman, forgot to mention your name in the comment, just see if you could connect to mysql through command line to the server